# 2 Protractor Tests, practically identical, one succeeds, one times out

Tags: protractor

This one is confusing. I have two tests that are practically identical in setup and one of them runs to completion and the other times out waiting for protractor to sync with the page. I already know about setting `browser.ignoreSynchronization`. My login page is not angularized so I turn it off **before** the login and turn it back on **after** I've successfully navigated to the first angular page as you can see here in my login function:

```
public login(username: string, password: string, wait = true): Promise<void> {
    util.isAngularSite(false); //turning it off here
    this.go(); //gets login page
    this.userNameInput.sendKeys(username);
    this.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
    this.loginButton.click();

    if (wait) {
        return NewUserListPage.waitForPageLoad().then(() => {
            return util.isAngularSite(true); //turning it back on here
        });
    } else {
        return promise.fulfilled<void>();
    }
}
```

And `util.isAngularSite()` could be better but is like this:

```
isAngularSite(flag: boolean): Promise<void> {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
    return promise.fulfilled<void>();
}
```

The setup in both of my tests is practically identical except for one function call. I know it seems like the obvious culprit would be the difference in the two tests but I'm having a hard time believing there isn't something else that's going on. I can't figure out why one would be timing out waiting for angular and the other works just fine. Wondering if anyone who has run into this before has a solution (I can't be the only one)? Here is my `beforeAll()` for both tests.

This one gives me the error `Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.`

```
//all the imports are exactly the same
import AllTheThings from "..."

describe("some tests", () => {

const adminUsername = browser.params.testdomain.username;
const password = browser.params.testdomain.password;
const domain = browser.params.testdomain.domain;
const servicesToAdd = [ServiceType.SomeTestServiceType];    

let newUserName: string;
let newUserEmail: string;

beforeAll(() => {
    LoginPage.login(adminUsername, password);

    //add new user
    NewUserListPage.selectAddUser();
    UserAddPage.addNewRandomUser(false, false, false, servicesToAdd)
        .then((name: string) => {
            newUserName = name;
            newUserEmail = util.generateEmailAddress(newUserName, domain);
        });

    NewUserListPage.waitForPageLoad();
});
```

This one succeeds:

```
//all the imports are exactly the same
import AllTheThings from "..."

describe("some other tests", () => {

const adminUsername = browser.params.testdomain.username;
const password = browser.params.testdomain.password;
const domain = browser.params.someOtherDomainName;
const servicesToAdd = [ServiceType.SomeOtherServiceType];

let newUserName: string;
let newUserEmail: string;

beforeAll(() => {
    LoginPage.login(adminUsername, password);

    //add new user
    NewUserListPage.selectAddUser();
    UserAddPage.addUserToSpecificDomain(domain, false, false, false, servicesToAdd)
        .then((name: string) => {
            newUserName = name;
            newUserEmail = util.generateEmailAddress(newUserName, domain);
        });

    NewUserListPage.waitForPageLoad();
});
```

The stacktrace says it timed out `While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(link text, Add User)` which is my Add User button. This button is clicked in the `NewUserListPage.selectAddUser()` function. Why would it be timing out for one test and not the other? It's also consistent, the same test always fails and succeeds. Any ideas?

Comment: I would put a `browser.pause` after the `Login.login(adminUsername, password)`. This would be interesting to see if your timing for `waitForPageLoad` works. Also, I would be interested to know if `window.name` is set properly... this should be verified in the console window that is paused. See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/browser.ts#L676. Good luck!